How to download a csv file from assets folder when click an anchor tag using react Js
I am trying to download a CSV file which resides in my project assets folder by clicking an anchor tag. But when i do this i got an error message like this ""File wasn't available on site". Tried many solutions, but none of them work.
My snippets are below. Any help is much appreciated.
 <a href="/assets/UserListSample.csv" download="UserListSample.csv">
    Click here
 </a>


You've got two options:
1 Import the file
import UserListSample from 'path/to/the/assets/UserListSample.csv';

export default function DownloadAnchor() {
  return (
    <a href={UserListSample} download="UserListSample.csv">
      Click here
    </a>
  )
}

Yor bundler should automaticaly bundle the file and adjust the href.
2 Place the file in the public folder
Given the snippet:
 <a href="/assets/UserListSample.csv" download="UserListSample.csv">
    Click here
 </a>

I conclude you should put the file in public/assets/UserListSample.csv; bundlers put everything from the public folder into the package as-is, so it should be available for download after you run the app. You need to put the right path in the code yourself.
3 If above doesn't work
It's probably bundler's fault. Try building the app (probably npm run build) and investigate the contents of the built package - see if the file is there somewhere. If it's not then it means it's not bundled properly. Search for UserListSample in other files to find that anchor you made - see what the path is - does it actually point to the file?
You can also just share more code, including package.json and other files related to how you run your app. The CodeSandbox is a great tool for this (even if the sandbox might have some limitations disallowing to actually download files, a Proof of Concept can still be made).

Thanks for the comment, unfortunately both the options doesn't work for me. I can't able to import the file from the path as suggested option 1. Tried second option too and it always showing the error "File wasn't available on site".

Always try to place the assets in the app_name/static/data folder


<a  href={ window.location.origin+'/root_folder/static/data/example.csv' }
                  download={'download.csv'}
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  Sample CSV
                </a>



